# UK visa for medical consultation

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, medical-tourism

If I apply for a UK visa, am I guaranteed to get it for a medical consultation if I have already made an appointment?

Answer (score 14):

There is no guarantee that someone who applies for a UK visa with a scheduled medical appointment will have their application approved. Such a policy would make little sense, as anyone would be able to make an appointment and get a visa.

The Entry Clearance Officer will review the totality of your application and personal circumstances and decide whether or not to grant your application.